# Error when deploying a smart contract with w3.eth.contract(): "The method eth_sendTransaction is not supported"

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py, hyperledger-besu

I'm using Web3.py, and a permissioned Hyperledger Besu network.

When trying to use w3.eth.contract(...) method to deploy a smart contract into the network, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32604, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction is not supported. Use eth_sendRawTransaction to send a signed transaction to Besu.'}
```

I suppose that eth_sendTransaction is being called when executing w3.eth.contract(...). Is there any other way of deploying a contract without ending up with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign the transaction before sending, more detail: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to use Infura node or similar.

[You need to sign the transaction locally with Web3.py and have your app to manage the private key for you](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html).